# python pygogo throws error, no module named builtins

Tags: python-2.7, logging, raspberry-pi3

I am using python and pygogo over raspberry pi 3 b, for error loggin.

After executing python program I am getting an error 
`pygogo no module named builtins`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing `future` module worked for me.

```
sudo pip install future
```